# Show number of posts AND number on current page

Tags: posts, pagination

I know how to show the total number of posts in a site, but is there a way to show the number of posts the page you're on is displaying?

For example, I want to show this at the bottom of each of my blog pages (8 posts per page);

```
Index - "Showing posts 1 through 8 of 294 total"
Page2 - "Showing posts 9 through 17 of 294 total"
Page3 - "Showing posts 18 through 26 of 294 total"
```

The posts are displayed in chronological order if that makes a difference.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
global $wp_query;
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$end = $ppp * $page;
$start = $end - $ppp + 1;
$total = $wp_query->found_posts;
echo "Showing posts $start through $end of $total total.";
```

Comment: `get_query_var('posts_per_page')` will overshoot on the last page of the results (sometimes the first). Has to use `$wp_query->post_count`.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm doing that right now, I tested the last solution and it works except on the last page.

That's working now and tested:

```
global $wp_query;
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$end = $ppp * $page;
$start = $end - $ppp + 1;
$total = $wp_query->found_posts;
if ($end > $total)
  $end = $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

@karpstrucking is really close but if the number of found posts is smaller than the number posts allowed per page, you'll echo a message like "Showing posts 1 through 12 of 9 total". To prevent this, the code should be updated to something like:

```
    global $wp_query;
    $page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
    $total = $wp_query->found_posts;
    $end = $ppp * $page;
    $start = $end - $ppp + 1;

    if( $ppp > $total ) {
        $results_summary_html = '<p>Showing ' . $total . ' out of ' . $total;
    } else if( $end > $total ) {
        $results_summary_html = '<p>Showing ' . $start . '-' . $total . ' out of ' . $total;
    } else {
        $results_summary_html = '<p>Showing ' . $start . '-' . $end . ' out of ' . $total;
    }
```