# Show number of posts and number on current page (revisited)

Tags: pagination

I'd like to be able to display the number of posts per page and the total number of posts. This question ([Show number of posts AND number on current page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155903/show-number-of-posts-and-number-on-current-page)) was previously asked and a solution provided by karpstrucking:

```
global $wp_query;
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$ppp = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$end = $ppp * $page;
$start = $end - $ppp + 1;
$total = $wp_query->found_posts;
echo "Showing posts $start through $end of $total total.";
```

This works really well (thanks karpstrucking), but there is an issue with the last page; if, for example, your pages are set to show 10 posts per page, and there are 23 posts in total, the pages will show:

- Showing posts 1 - 10 of 23
- Showing posts 11 - 20 of 23
- Showing posts 21 - **30** of 23

Some sort of conditional required, but unfortunately I really don't know where to start.

Any help *hugely* appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the way you calculate `$start` and `$end`:

```
$page  = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
$ppp   = get_query_var('posts_per_page');
$start = $ppp * ( $page - 1 ) + 1;
$end   = $start + $wp_query->post_count - 1; // Start post plus number of posts for current page (not *total* posts for the query)
```

Comment: Many thanks TheDeadMedic for your help!! This is very close, but not quite; I have plus 1 for the end number of all pages ('1 - 11 of 23', '11 - 21 of 23' & '21-24 of 23').

Comment: Sorry, should have worked a bit harder before commenting: I have it now: $end = $start + $wp_query->post_count - 1;  Thanks a million for your help!!